# Working with Irregular nodes/elements in json response from an API

Tags: c#, json, .net, .net-3.5

I have a situation while working with a JSON response from an API. To give a background, I am consuming an API from a source using a REST API using 3.5 .net framework.
Below is the part of the JSON output and I am kind of struggling to use it.

a)

```
"value": {
  "Description": "Total  Calculated things",
  "2018": "5,820,456 ",
  "2019": "2,957,447 "
}
```

The last 2 elements are dynamic, those are tend to change in API response. I was expecting the format like I have mentioned below, but at this point of given time the source provider is not able to change it as the API is used in many other different programs. And Changing the things in the source API will make other program owners to change.

b)

```
"value": {
    "Description": "Total  Calculated EQUITY AND LIABILITIES",
    "YearData": [ {
            "Data": "5,820,456",
            "Year": "2018"
        },
        {
            "Data": "2,957,447 ",
            "Year": "2019"
        } ]
}
```

Is there any way to overcome such thing> Any way to convert **a** to **b**?

EDIT
@Xerillio , Thanks . How can I achieve the same using below JSON format.

```
var json = @"
        {
    ""entityData"": [
        {
            ""name"": ""Statement of Comprehensive Income"",
            ""subattrOutput"": [
                {
                    ""name"": ""Sales"",
                    ""subattrOutput"": [],
                    ""value"": {
                        ""Description"": ""Sales "",
                        ""2018"": ""8,704,888 "",
                        ""2019"": ""4,760,717 ""
                    },
                    ""score"": ""99.5"",
                    ""valuetype"": ""object""
                },
                {
                    ""name"": ""Cost of goods sold"",
                    ""subattrOutput"": [],
                    ""value"": {
                        ""Description"": ""Cost of sales "",
                        ""2018"": ""(6,791,489) "",
                        ""2019"": ""(3,502,785) ""
                    },
                    ""score"": ""99.75"",
                    ""valuetype"": ""object""
                }
            ],
            ""value"": null,
            ""score"": ""98.63"",
            ""valuetype"": ""object""
        }
    ]
}";
```

Answer (score 0):

I wish this was more easy, but i just got it here:

```
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json1 = @"{""value"": {""Description"": ""Total  Calculated things"",""2018"": ""5,820,456 "",""2019"": ""2,957,447 ""}}";
            string json2 = @"{""value"": {""Description"": ""Total  Calculated EQUITY AND LIABILITIES"",""YearData"": [ {""Data"": ""5,820,456"",""Year"": ""2018""},{""Data"": ""2,957,447 "",""Year"": ""2019""} ]}}";

            var obj1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjectResult>(json1);
            var obj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjectResult>(json2);

            var res1 = CastObject<Result1>(obj1.Value.ToString());
            var res2 = CastObject<Result2>(obj2.Value.ToString());

            var invalidRes1 = CastObject<Result1>(obj2.Value.ToString());
            var invalidRes2 = CastObject<Result2>(obj1.Value.ToString());

            Console.WriteLine(res1);
            Console.WriteLine(res2);
        }

        public static T CastObject<T>(string obj)
        {
            return !TryCastObject(obj, out T result) ? default : result;
        }


        public static bool TryCastObject<TOut>(string objToCast, out TOut obj)
        {
            try
            {
                obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TOut>(objToCast);
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                obj = default;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    public class ObjectResult
    {
        public object Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result1
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "description")] public string Description { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "2018")] public string _2018 { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "2019")] public string _2019 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result2
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Description")] public string Description { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "YearData")] public List<YearData> YearData { get; set; }
    }

    public class YearData
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Data")] public string Data { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Year")] public string Year { get; set; }
    }
```

It is A LOT of work and sincerely, as there more nodes in the json i think that using JObject is the best option, and you will have to do a deserealization in more than 1 step :(

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how large the JSON structure is you could deserialize it into a `Dictionary` and manually map it to the proper format:

```
var json = @"
{
    ""value"": {
        ""Description"": ""Total  Calculated things"",
        ""2018"": ""5,820,456 "",
        ""2019"": ""2,957,447 ""
    }
}";

var badObj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<BadFormat>(json);
var result = new WrapperType
{
    Value = new ProperlyFormattedType()
};

foreach (var pair in badObj.Value)
{
    if (pair.Key == "Description")
    {
        result.Value.Description = pair.Value;
    }
    else if (int.TryParse(pair.Key, out int _))
    {
        result.Value.YearData
            .Add(new DatedValues
            {
                Year = pair.Key,
                Data = pair.Value
            });
    }
}

// Data models...

public class BadFormat
{
    [JsonPropertyName("value")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Value { get; set; }
}


public class WrapperType
{
    public ProperlyFormattedType Value { get; set; }
}

public class ProperlyFormattedType
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<DatedValues> YearData { get; set; } = new List<DatedValues>();
}

public class DatedValues
{
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

See an [example fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4OpDLT).